# RecyclerView gets IndexOutOfBoundsException when Scrolling (Retrofit2 + Library Section RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to make the recyclerview section to display 4 data from the mysql database. I use a library of several references that I get, when the data is dummy it doesn't have a problem, but when I change it into the data I take from the database I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5 Is there a solution for me?

Here is the exception :

```
2018-12-28 03:00:51.988 7929-7929/rifafauzi6.id.sectionrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: rifafauzi6.id.sectionrecyclerview, PID: 7929
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:427)
    at rifafauzi6.id.sectionrecyclerview.adapter.QuestionAdapter.onBindItemViewHolder(QuestionAdapter.java:76)
    at io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.Section.onBindContentViewHolder(Section.java:295)
    at io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:293)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is the code QuestionAdapter.java :

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends StatelessSection {

private String title;
private List<Question> listQuestion;
private Context context;

private LayoutInflater inflter;
public static ArrayList<String> kdPertanyaan;
public static ArrayList<String> kdKuesioner;
public static ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers;

public QuestionAdapter(Context context, String title, List<Question> listQuestion) {
    super(SectionParameters.builder()
            .itemResourceId(R.layout.list_pertanyaan)
            .headerResourceId(R.layout.list_title)
            .build());
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.listQuestion = listQuestion;
    kdPertanyaan = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listQuestion.size(); i++) {
        kdPertanyaan.add("Nilai tidak boleh kosong");
    }
    kdKuesioner = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listQuestion.size(); i++) {
        kdKuesioner.add("Nilai tidak boleh kosong");
    }
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listQuestion.size(); i++) {
        selectedAnswers.add("Jawaban tidak boleh kosong");
    }

    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
}

public void setListQuestion(List<Question> listQuestion) {
    this.listQuestion = listQuestion;
}

@Override
public int getContentItemsTotal() {
    return listQuestion.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
    Question question = listQuestion.get(position);
    itemHolder.txtKdPertanyaan.setText(kdPertanyaan.set(position, question.getKd_pertanyaan()));
    itemHolder.txtKdKuesioner.setText(kdKuesioner.set(position, question.getKd_kuesioner()));
    itemHolder.txtNo.setText(question.getNo());
    itemHolder.txtPertanyaan.setText(question.getPertanyaan());
    itemHolder.question = question;
    itemHolder.rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(position, "1");
        }
    });

    itemHolder.rb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(position, "3");
        }
    });

    itemHolder.rb5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(position, "5");
        }
    });

    itemHolder.rb7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(position, "7");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
    return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

    headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
}

class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvTitle) TextView tvTitle;

    HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.kd_pertanyaan) TextView txtKdPertanyaan;
    @BindView(R.id.kd_kuesioner) TextView txtKdKuesioner;
    @BindView(R.id.no) TextView txtNo;
    @BindView(R.id.question) TextView txtPertanyaan;
    @BindView(R.id.rbValueOf1) RadioButton rb1;
    @BindView(R.id.rbValueOf3) RadioButton rb3;
    @BindView(R.id.rbValueOf5) RadioButton rb5;
    @BindView(R.id.rbValueOf7) RadioButton rb7;

    Question question;
    ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code for display data :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.rv_pertanyaan) RecyclerView rvPertanyaan;
ProgressDialog loading;

private SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter;

String KS01 = "KS01";
String KS02 = "KS02";
String KS03 = "KS03";
String KS04 = "KS04";

String titleA = "A. Kompetensi Pedagogik : kemampuan mengelola proses pembelajaran mahasiswa.";
String titleB = "B. Kompetensi Profesional : kemampuan penguasaan materi pelajaran secara luas dan mendalam.";
String titleC = "C. Kompetensi Kepribadian : kemampuan kepribadian yang mantap, berakhlak mulia, arif, dan berwibawa serta menjadi teladan mahasiswa.";
String titleD = "D. Kompetensi Sosial : kemampuan berkomunikasi dan berinteraksi secara efektif dan efisien dengan mahasiswa, sesama dosen, orangtua/wali, dan masyarakat sekitar";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

    loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    callQuestion1(KS01);
    callQuestion2(KS02);
    callQuestion3(KS03);
    callQuestion4(KS04);

    rvPertanyaan.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rvPertanyaan.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

}

private void callQuestion1(String kd_pertanyaan){
    loading.setMessage("Loading ...");
    loading.setCancelable(false);
    loading.show();
    BaseApiService apiService = Server.getUrl().create(BaseApiService.class);
    Call<ResponsModelQuestion> getdata = apiService.getPertanyaan(kd_pertanyaan);
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsModelQuestion>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Response<ResponsModelQuestion> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("onResponse", "Message : " + Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getKode());
                List<Question> listPertanyaan = response.body().getResult();

                QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titleA, listPertanyaan);
                adapter.setListQuestion(listPertanyaan);
                sectionAdapter.addSection(adapter);
                rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
            }
            else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Mengambil Data Kuesioner !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.e("onFailure : ","Message : "+String.valueOf(t.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Menghubungkan Internet !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void callQuestion2(String kd_pertanyaan){
    loading.setMessage("Loading ...");
    loading.setCancelable(false);
    loading.show();
    BaseApiService apiService = Server.getUrl().create(BaseApiService.class);
    Call<ResponsModelQuestion> getdata = apiService.getPertanyaan(kd_pertanyaan);
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsModelQuestion>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Response<ResponsModelQuestion> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("onResponse", "Message : " + Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getKode());
                List<Question> listPertanyaan = response.body().getResult();

                QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titleB, listPertanyaan);
                adapter.setListQuestion(listPertanyaan);
                sectionAdapter.addSection(adapter);
                rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
            }
            else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Mengambil Data Kuesioner !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.e("onFailure : ","Message : "+String.valueOf(t.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Menghubungkan Internet !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void callQuestion3(String kd_pertanyaan){
    loading.setMessage("Loading ...");
    loading.setCancelable(false);
    loading.show();
    BaseApiService apiService = Server.getUrl().create(BaseApiService.class);
    Call<ResponsModelQuestion> getdata = apiService.getPertanyaan(kd_pertanyaan);
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsModelQuestion>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Response<ResponsModelQuestion> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("onResponse", "Message : " + Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getKode());
                List<Question> listPertanyaan = response.body().getResult();

                QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titleC, listPertanyaan);
                adapter.setListQuestion(listPertanyaan);
                sectionAdapter.addSection(adapter);
                rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
            }
            else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Mengambil Data Kuesioner !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.e("onFailure : ","Message : "+String.valueOf(t.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Menghubungkan Internet !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void callQuestion4(String kd_pertanyaan){
    loading.setMessage("Loading ...");
    loading.setCancelable(false);
    loading.show();
    BaseApiService apiService = Server.getUrl().create(BaseApiService.class);
    Call<ResponsModelQuestion> getdata = apiService.getPertanyaan(kd_pertanyaan);
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsModelQuestion>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Response<ResponsModelQuestion> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("onResponse", "Message : " + Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getKode());
                List<Question> listPertanyaan = response.body().getResult();

                QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titleD, listPertanyaan);
                adapter.setListQuestion(listPertanyaan);
                sectionAdapter.addSection(adapter);
                rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
            }
            else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Mengambil Data Kuesioner !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponsModelQuestion> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.e("onFailure : ","Message : "+String.valueOf(t.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gagal Menghubungkan Internet !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I believe the error is linked to the QuestionAdapter class where you are setting the position of 5 on the setOnCheckedChangeListener event for the RadioButton. The same is also stated by the Exception error. Within the Exception you have Index 5 and Size 5. It's important to remember that Index starts at 0 and size starts at 1. Therefore, you are setting the position beyond the size of the array list.

Comment: can u give me a solution ?

Comment: What purpose do the radiobuttons serve?

Comment: radio button for sending value into db, but before that, i have the problem for get data like this post

Comment: Can you try moving the setLayoutManager and setHasFixedSize(true) before callQuestion functions and also delete rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter) at the end of onCreate as you're already doing this within the callQuestion function.

Comment: I can post the same answer and you can accept the answer. I can add more information for other readers so they are aware of how it was rectified.

Comment: i will try with 5x run and stil not work, sometimes I get the same force close with the error, I don't know why

Comment: Please message me on Discord as comments shouldn't be used for conversations like these. My discord tag is in my bio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code is causing the Exception:

```
rvPertanyaan.setAdapter(sectionAdapter)
```

Removing this should rectify the issue and the code doesn't serve any purpose. The reason being because this adapter is set at the end of every callQuestion function if it obtains a successful response. Alongside this, you can also move the location of the

```
rvPertanyaan.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Above the `callQuestion1();` function because it's important to ensure the layout manager is set before setting the adapter.

One thing you must note about the IndexOutOfBoundsException is the Index and Size. The size of the list starts from 1; whereas, the index starts from 0. When you are trying to access a index with is above the size, it will result in the IndexOutOfBoundsException.